# Сериализация в usercontrol только нужных свойств

Tags: .net, visual-basic, vb.net, usercontrol

Имеется простой (для примера) UserControl, с определенным набором пользовательских свойств.

```
Public Class LayoutEditor


Private _element_background_color As Color
Public Property ElementBackgroundColor() As Color
    Get
        Return _element_background_color
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        _element_background_color = value
    End Set
End Property


Private _element_border_color As Color
Public Property ElementBorderColor() As Color
    Get
        Return _element_border_color
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        _element_border_color = value
    End Set
End Property


Private _selected_object As Object
Public Property SelectedObject() As Object
    Get
        Return _selected_object
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        _selected_object = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Понятно что он имеет **еще очень много родительских свойств**.
Задача сохранить состояние объекта *SOAP* серриализацией, но возникает проблема в том что нужно в конечный xml файл сохранить только определенные свойства, а не все подряд.
Как сие реализовать.

**UPDATE**
Родителем у разрабатываемого usercontrol является

```
Inherits
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно.

`UserControl`, как и любой визуальный элемент, вовсе не предназначен для сериализации. Сериализуйте контент, а не представление.

---

В вашем приложении должны быть отделены данные от их визуального представления. Вы можете игнорировать этот принцип, и смешать всё в одну кучу, но проблемы, подобные этой, будут возникать постоянно. Делайте лучше правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас нету доступа к исходному кода сохраняемого контрола, то cамым простым вариантом для вас будет написать свой класс, который будет содержать необходимые вам поля и при сохранении(сериализации) просто пробрасывать данные из контрола в ваш класс.

Если у вас есть доступ к исходнику, то вам нужно просто добавить аттрибут для игнорирования поля сериализатором. Пример:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization


Public Class Group
    Public GroupName As String

    'Это поле будет проигнорировано.
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()> Public Comment As String
End Class
```

Comment: Имелось в виду, что у usercontrola есть родитель System.Windows.Forms.UserControl, соответственно исходника нету. Про то как проигнорировать свойство имея исходник естественно я в курсе.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь тогда единственный вариант создавать дополнительный класс.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить таким образом.

1. Создаем отдельный класс, куда выносим свойства, требующие сериализации.
2. Привязываем ("биндим") свойства контрола на свойства созданного объекта
3. Теперь можно сериализовать и десериализовать объект

Comment: 1) имеется, 2) не знаю как сделать, можете привести пример как это делается или ссылку на пример.

Comment: Еще суть в том что контрол содержит массив других контролов которые в итоге и надо биндить и потом серриализовать, то есть биндить свойства контрола и класса надо динамически.